# Are these methods to send JSON using Ajax equivalent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, serialization

I continue to see 2 different approach to send JSON data through an HTTP request using JQuery Ajax but I can't understand which is the most correct and which could have some drawbacks.

**Are they equivalent?
Which one of these is the most correct with less drawbacks?**

**FIRST APPROACH (implicit serialization)**

```
  $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type : "POST", 
        dataType : 'json',
        data : JavaScriptObject, 
        success : function(result) {
           ...               
        },
        error: function() {
           ...
        }
    })
```

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string...Object must be Key/Value pairs

In this case it seems to me that if I have a Javascript Object like

```
var a = {
    name: 'a',
    age: 10
 }
```

I don't need to serialize it before to send it because JQuery will do it for me giving an output string like `check=check2&radio=radio1`.
Possibly I can `json_encode` the query string on the server-side to have JSON data again.

**SECOND APPROACH (serialize(); JSON.stringify();  serializeArray())**

*1.serialize()*

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            type : "POST", 
            dataType : 'json',
            data : $("#form").serialize(), 
            success : function(result) {
               ...               
            },
            error: function() {
               ...
            }
        })
```

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation.

In this case I understood that `serialize()`create a query string like `check=check2&radio=radio1`. 
Possibly I can `json_encode` the query string on the server-side to have JSON data again.
So I'd say that in this case `serialize()` acts like the implicit serialization in the first approach.

*2. JSON.stringify(), serializeArray()*

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type : "POST", 
        dataType : 'json',
        data : JSON.stringify($("#form").serializeArray()), 
        success : function(result) {
           ...               
        },
        error: function() {
           ...
        }
    })
```

> The .serializeArray() method creates a JavaScript array of objects, 
>   ready to be encoded as a JSON string.

Like this (2 and 1 text from a form)

```
[
  {
    name: "a",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    value: "2"
  }
]
```

> The stringify function returns a String in JSON format representing an
>   ECMAScript value... The value parameter is an ECMAScript value, which
>   is usually an object or array...

Producing an output string like this

```
'[{"name": "a","value": "1"},{"name": "b",value: "2"}]'
```

which I can encode to JSON data again.

Thanks

Comment: The serialise is for form data.  If your just sending a javascript object, then the JSON.stringify is the option.

Comment: But why it works also without JSON.stringify (first example)? Is it the same?

Comment: Because jQuery sees data as an object, it will just JSON.stringify for you.